# How to add multiple models to a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model

I'm trying to add the contents of at least two tables to a view in my C# & ASP.NET MVC app in VS2022. I've created both models login and category and then added anew model called `BothModels` which looks like this:

```
public class BothModels
{
    List<LoginModel>? LoginList { get; set; }
    List<CategoriesModel>? CategoriesList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my controller I'm trying to add both collections to `BothModels` to pass to my view. This is the code I've got so far:

```
List<LoginModel> loginDtl = getLogin();
List<CategoriesModel> ctgDtl = geCategory();
BothModels bothModels = new BothModels();
        .
// How to add both lists to bothModels here?
        .
return bothModels;
```

I need to find a way to add the two lists to `bothModels` and then after passing to the view how to display both lists.

The view will look something like this:

```
       @Model BothModels

       @foreach (var line in @Model)
       {
          line.loginModel.User
          //...
       }
```

Can someone help me finish off the code as I've tried a number of different approaches with no success

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the two list in your `BothModels` ViewModel to your retrieved lists like this:

```
List<LoginModel> loginDtl = getLogin();
List<CategoriesModel> ctgDtl = geCategory();
BothModels bothModels = new BothModels();
        
// This is how you can add both the list in your viewmodel
bothModels.LoginList=loginDtl;
bothModels.CategoriesList=ctgDtl;

return bothModels;
```

View will look like:

```
   @Model BothModels

   @foreach (var line in @Model.LoginList)
   {
      line.loginModel.User
      //...
   }
   
   @foreach (var line in @Model.CategoriesList)
   {
      line.CategoriesModel
      //...
   }
```

Add the `public` access modifier in your `BothModels` to make your properties accessible:

```
public class BothModels
{
    public List<LoginModel>? LoginList { get; set; }
    public List<CategoriesModel>? CategoriesList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for your reply. When I tried your code I get the error LoginList and CategoriesList are inaccessable due to their protection level. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

-> Follow my code :-
-> BothModels:-

```
public class BothModels
{
    public List<LoginModel> LoginList { get; set; }
    public List<CategoriesModel> CategoriesList { get; set; }

    public BothModels()
    {
        LoginList = new List<LoginModel>();
        CategoriesList = new List<CategoriesModel>();
    }
}
```

-> You can assign the lists to the BothModels :-

```
List<LoginModel> loginDtl = getLogin();
List<CategoriesModel> ctgDtl = getCategory();
BothModels bothModels = new BothModels();
bothModels.LoginList = loginDtl;
bothModels.CategoriesList = ctgDtl;

return View(bothModels);
```

->in your view,you can access the lists using the properties of the bothModels object:-

```
@model BothModels
@foreach (var login in Model.LoginList)
{
    <p>@login.User</p>
    <!-- Display other properties of LoginModel as needed -->
}

@foreach (var category in Model.CategoriesList)
{
    <p>@category.CategoryName</p>
    <!-- Display other properties of CategoriesModel as needed -->
}
```

-> replace User and Categoryname with your actual properties , which in you can use in loginmodel and categoriesModel.